# writing/reading text file vs Embedded DB -

Tags: java, javafx, embedded-database

In my app I want to store some info (maybe it can be called log?) after every session. It consists of something like 20 strings (each string 10-15 values of usual type - int, date, string, boolean).
ALL of the data is to be kept saved (let say the average number of sessions will be 20 per day). Then, I want to enable the option of seeing that info (including previous sessions) via JavaFX TableView. Before displaying on TableVIew I ll put some easy filter (2-3 parameters)

My app is planned to be portable (by this I mean without installing to PC but putting the overall folder-including JRE-on USB Flash). This means that if I chose DB I m to chose EMBEDDED version.

I m quite novice in Java so I do not know which way is preferred. What considerations I should take in account? Is there a third option?

Thanks for advance

I want to save ALL the data (let say the average number of sessions will be 20 per day ). Before displaying on TableVIew I ll put some easy filter (2-3 parameters)

Comment: It depends on what you need the data for, and how long you need to persist it for, and what the format of your data looks like. If it's really simple data you could store it to something like a text file for each run of the program inside a directory and load up all the files in said directory when you need to display it.

Comment: It is planned to be something "light". The values ( I ve called them "words") are of usual type - int, date, string, boolean. I want to save ALL the data (let say the average number of sessions will be 20 per day ). Before  displaying on TableVIew I ll put some easy filter (2-3 parameters).

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer here, it is a matter of opinion.  [Using an embedded database](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/4957967) such as [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), is pretty straightforward and lightweight (IMO).  A third option could be the [preferences API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html).

Comment: jewelsea : I see... So I m looking for "opinions" :)))

Comment: Be careful, StackOverflow has a close reason titled "Primarily opinion based" :-)

Comment: jewelsea, subject to mentioned numbers (15 sessions/ per day * 15 records / per session* 180 days = 40K records)  - does it make difference which embedded DB  to chose? I m inclining to Derby because it has more tutorials as far as I see

Comment: Of course the choice of embed database makes a difference, but it is more a function of personal preference than strengths or limitations of a given option, any half-decent embedded database will easily be able to handle what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much! Does Derby fit "half-decent " definition? :)

Comment: You can do both.  Both derby and h2 can read/write text files.  I would start with text.  If you're reading the entire file/database into memory, there's no real advantage to a database.  If you want to filter the read, then indexed databases are great.

Comment: I am sorry, I m afraid I didn t get. What does it mean "reading... INTO memory"? My dilemma is the choice between establishing one (or per day?) text files and reading/writing with Streams or to work with embedded DB such as H2 or Derby and just use SQL. That is how I see my options. Am I right or maybe I do not understand something significant? Pls advise.

Comment: This discussion seems to be making this *more* opinion-based, not less...